# C# Better way to handle multiple if/else if statements

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, dictionary, switch-statement

I have a class that handles incoming over-the-air messages and parses them. Depending on the output of the command, I need to handle some UI modifications such as highlighting labels, adding text to textboxes etc. The first option I was using is:

```
void IncomingMessageIfStatements(Message msg, Host host)
        {
            byte resp;
            if (ParseMessageOptionOne(msg, out resp))
            {
                // Do some windows form stuff
            }    

            else if (ParseMessageOptionTwo(msg, out resp))
            {
                // Do some windows form stuff
            }

            else if (ParseMessageOptionThree(msg, out resp))
            {
                // Do some windows form stuff
            }
        }

        private bool ParseMessageOptionOne(Message msg, out byte resp)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        private bool ParseMessageOptionTwo(Message msg, out byte resp)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        private bool ParseMessageOptionThree(Message msg, out byte resp)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

This works, but I will have more `else if` statements and it could get ugly. The next way I looked at doing is:

```
void IncomingMessageSwitchStatements(Message msg, Host host)
        {
            byte resp = 0;
            byte someByte = 0;
            bool output = false;
            switch (someByte)
            {
                case 1:
                    output = ParseMessageOptionOne(msg, out resp);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    output = ParseMessageOptionTwo(msg, out resp);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    output = ParseMessageOptionThree(msg, out resp);
                    break;
                default:
                    //handle exception here
                    break;
            }

            if (output && resp == 0x01)
            {
                UpdateUiFromHere();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateUiFromHere()
        {
            // handle UI updates here
        }
```

This looks much cleaner and works as intended. But then I started looking at `Dictionary<byte, Func<bool>>` and thought maybe that was a better approach to solving the handling of multiple conditions incoming (possibly 20).

Any suggestions on the best practice I should go for, given whats needed?

Comment: The `switch` version will always execure default branch... You say it works as intended?

Comment: Seems the "if else" block is not logically the same as the  "switch case" one. ParseMessageOptionX returns bool, where the someByte comes from?

Comment: switch is better than if/else if/else.  However, if there are a large number of conditions, then a lookup table (dictionary) would make your code more concise.

Comment: You should check out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206816/clarification-of-avoid-if-else-advice
And I think if you have more than 10 if-condition or case-switch ,you can replace them by polymorphism

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser I pulled some code out for security reasons, but the `case` is there for clarity. The `case` is obviously based on `byte` coming in from the message.

Comment: @AwakeningByte The `someByte` comes in from the `msg.SomeProperty`, which is handled in the methods in the `if/else` example. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @AlexNguyen Thank you for the link. Do you have an example on the polymorphism?

Answer (score 3):

Since what you want to do is to "Call method with the same signature based on index number", you could use `delegate` and list them in a `Dictionary` (or in a `List` if the index starts from `0`) to make your intention clear.

```
public delegate bool ParseMessage(Message msg, out byte resp);
```

And then list it using `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<byte, ParseMessage> parser = new Dictionary<byte, ParseMessage>(){
    {1, new ParseMessage(ParseMessageOptionOne)},
    {2, new ParseMessage(ParseMessageOptionTwo)},
    {3, new ParseMessage(ParseMessageOptionThree)}
};
```

or using `List`

```
List<ParseMessage> parser = new List<ParseMessage>(){
    new ParseMessage(ParseMessageOptionOne),
    new ParseMessage(ParseMessageOptionTwo),
    new ParseMessage(ParseMessageOptionThree)
};
```

And call it like this:

```
bool result = parser[resp](msg, out resp); //dictionary
bool result = parser[resp-1](msg, out resp); //list
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move the parsing to *inside* the Message class itself.

```
Options option = msg.GetOption();
```

I would also make an enum for all your options:

```
public enum Options {
    One,
    Two,
    None
}
```

Then write your code to make use of that however you need to...

```
if (option == Options.One)
// or
switch(option)
// etc.
```

Hard to recommend more since I can't tell what `UpdateUiFromHere()` does since it takes no parms...but this should be some good food for thought.

Comment: Those can be good recommendations for writing self-documenting code, but doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @JonathanWood, the OPs question is almost enough to ask to reword or close as too broad: "Any suggestions on the best practice I should go for, given whats needed?" My answer was more along the lines of using `encapsulation` so the Message class contains all logic, which would be a "best practice". It is hard on some questions to decide to answer for Question X, or help to solve Problem Y (which maybe is not asked directly in X by the OPs sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

You can as well change the method signature of ParseMessageOptionOne, ParseMessageOptionTwo, ParseMessageOptionThree to return a response object that encapsulates output, response and use Func built-in delegate to store methods:

```
public struct ParseResponse
{
    public bool output;
    public byte response;
}

class ParseOptions
{
    Func<Message, ParseResponse>[] options = null;

    public ParseOptions()
    {
        options = new Func<Message, ParseResponse>[]{
            ParseMessageOptionOne,
            ParseMessageOptionTwo,
            ParseMessageOptionThree
        };
    }

    public void IncomingMessageSwitchStatements(Message msg, Host host)
    {            
        byte someByte = 2;

        var response = options[someByte](msg);

        if (response.output && response.response == 0x01)
        {
            //UpdateUiFromHere();
        }
    }

    private ParseResponse ParseMessageOptionThree(Message msg)
    {
        return new ParseResponse { output = true };
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use LINQ to loop through a list of delegate methods, and short-circut as soon as a `true` condition is found.

```
private delegate bool ParseMessageWrapper(Message msg, out byte resp);

void IncomingMessageSwitchStatements(Message msg, Host host)
{
    byte resp = 0;
    bool output = false;

    var parseMethods = new List<ParseMessageWrapper>()
    {
        new ParseMessageWrapper(ParseMessageOptionOne),
        new ParseMessageWrapper(ParseMessageOptionTwo),
        new ParseMessageWrapper(ParseMessageOptionThree)
    };

    output = parseMethods.Any(func => func.Invoke(msg, out resp));

    if (output && resp == 0x01)
    {
        UpdateUiFromHere();
    }
}
```